# ExtJS 4.1. which are best components for create sidebar menu (as have Worpdress in left panel)

Tags: javascript, extjs, components, sidebar

I am Newbie in Extjs and use version 4.1. I want to know which component is best to use into one Ext.Viewport, to have left panel sidebar (like in Wordpress admin, like Wordpress Post/Page/Media/Categories/Settings menus etc). I want to be vertical menu, one under the other.

I found samples with Ext.tree, Ext.menu or vertical Tabs for sidebar, but i dont really know if for Ext.Viewport (not MVC Application) it is one best approach to use components in "items" property.

```
Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
    layout: 'border',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'box',
        region: 'north'
        ....
    },{
        layout: 'border',
        id: 'sidebar',
        region:'west',
        items: HERE WANT SIDEBAR COMPONENT
        ....
    }, 
    {
        id: 'vbox-panel',
        region: 'center',
        defaultType: 'container',
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox'
        },
        defaults: {
            frame: true
        },
        items: [
            {
                height: 40,
                html: 'Top content'
                ....
            }, {
                id: 'content',
                layout: 'card',
                items: [content],
                flex: 2
                ....
            }, {
                flex: 2,
                html: 'Bottom comtent'
                ....
            }
        ]
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Thanks

UPDATE:
- write one comment with one simple solution, for beginers as me :)

Comment: I found one solutions, for beginers :) .... for above "HERE WANT SIDEBAR COMPONENT" can be replaced with an array of objects, type vbox, every object with html property for example: [{ html : "<a href='#'>Applications</a>", height: 30, border: false }, { html : "<a href='#'>Modules</a>", height: 30, border: false }]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a vertical toolbar like this : http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/toolbar/vertical-toolbars.html